# Large datasets, deviations and noise/signal

Tags: inference, descriptive-statistics, large-data

The below excerpt mentions that 'large deviations' are more attributable to variance than to information. What does the author mean when he says 'deviations'? Deviations from what? And why would it be the case that large datasets contain deviations that are more attributable to variance? These seem to be the foundations of his ensuing argument.

> But beyond that, big data means anyone can find fake statistical
>   relationships, since the spurious rises to the surface. This is
>   because **in large data sets, large deviations are vastly more
>   attributable to variance (or noise) than to information (or signal).**
>   It’s a property of sampling: In real life there is no cherry-picking,
>   but on the researcher’s computer, there is. Large deviations are
>   likely to be bogus.

Source: https://www.wired.com/2013/02/big-data-means-big-errors-people/

Comment: they are talking about large number of features see eg http://tylervigen.com/spurious-correlations

Comment: @seanv507 thanks for responding. I understand the large number of 'features' part, but what about the 'deviations' part. I graps what a deviation is, but I still wonder what the deviation is from, e.g. the mean? My confusion is furthered by the fact that this seems like it should be self-evident, but in my case it's not.

Comment: Its a piece in wired not a statistics text. So spurious correlation shows you high correlation for nonsensical association...that's a 'large deviation' from the expected 0 correlation.